# Continuous complex function from Rudin's Real and complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Lemma 10.29 from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, p. 314 of the third edition states that "if $f \in H(\Omega)$, then $g:\Omega \times \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by 
\begin{equation}
g(z, w) = \begin{cases} \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w} & \text{if } z \neq w\\
f'(z) & \text{if } w=z
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is continuous on $\Omega \times \Omega$".

His proof is the following:

"Let $a\in \Omega$. Since $f$ is analytic, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subset \Omega$ and $|f'(\zeta)-f'(z_0)|<\epsilon$ for all $\zeta \in B(a,r)$. Getting $z,w\in B(a,r)$, then $\zeta(t)=(1-t)z+tw \in B(a,r)$ for $0\le t\le 1$. Now just use that $g(z,w)-g(a,a)=\int_0^1[f'(\zeta(t))-f'(a)]dt$ and the $\epsilon$-bound to get the desired continuity."

He goes a bit too fast on the equality $g(z,w)-g(a,a)=\int_0^1[f'(\zeta(t))-f'(a)]dt$, and I don't get where it comes from. Could someone help on that point?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $g(a,a) = f'(a) = \int_0^1 f'(a) dt$, and $\int_0^1 f'(\zeta(t)) dt = \int_0^1 f'(\zeta(t)) \zeta'(t) / \zeta'(t) dt  = \int_0^1 f'(\zeta(t)) \zeta'(t) dt / (w - z)  = (f(\zeta(1)) - f(\zeta(0))) / (w - z) = g(z, w)$

Comment: Thank you! Everything clear :).